# no supported translation to SQL Help Linq -> SQL

Tags: linq

I have a query that has a where clause that checks if the data element is contained within a list.

This query executes fine:

```
results = awardedStats.Where(r => guidReq.Contains(r.RequirementId) || orgAcr.Contains(r.Division))
                                                .Select(r => r);
```

however this does not:

```
results = awardedStats.Where(r => guidReq.Contains(r.RequirementId) || orgAcrId.Contains(r.guidDivisionId))
                                                .Select(r => r);
```

r.division is a string and orgAcr is a List

r.guidDivisionId is a Guid and orgAcrId is a List

I know that each list get the correct values, I can check the list in the debugger, but if I run the first query, everything runs through fine, if I run the second query I get an error stating that the member "guidDivisionId" has no supported translation to SQL

Answer (score 0):

If `orgAcrId` is a `List<Guid>` and `r.guidDivisionId` is a `uniqueidentifier` column in SQL Server, this should be fine.  Are you sure the column name isn't `r.DivisionId`?

Comment: Yes it is a property of an object -     public Guid guidDivisionId { get; set; }...


 var data = from r in db.tblRequirements
                   where statusPreAward.Contains(r.strStatusId) && r.tblTeams.Any(x=>x.guidPersonId == guidPersonId)
                   select new PreAStatistics
                   {
                       other fiels are here but I dont have enough space,
                       guidDivisionId = r.tblOrganizationContracting.guidOrgId
                   };

Comment: Is `orgAcrId` a `List<Guid>`?

Comment: Yes it is, and when I put a breakpoint on it I get 11 returned guids in the list (which is correct)

Answer (score 0):

Get all data from sql and call AsEnumarable() method on it and then apply the where. That way comparison would be done in memory and it won't complain about sql translation.

Another thing is that when you use contains, it's converted to Sql IN clause. All elements in the list are included in the IN clause. If your list has more than 2100 elements, then you would get sql exception saying that sql cannot accept more than 2100 parameters. Doing this kind of comparison in memory is safer.